# Count how many missing rows in pandas dataframe by user index

Tags: python, pandas

```
user   cat  val1  val2  val3
user1  cat1   3    NA     NA
       cat2   NA   NA     NA
       cat3   NA   NA     5
user2  cat1   NA   NA     NA
       cat2   NA   6      NA
       cat3   NA   NA     7
user3  cat1   4    NA     NA
       cat2   NA   NA     NA
       cat3   NA   NA     NA
```

In this dataframe df, user and cat are indices. I want to iterate by user, and count how many rows per each user have ALL NA values. (cat1 corresponds to val1 and etc)

In this example user1 and user2 have 1 missing row, and user3 has 2 missing rows.

EDIT: answer was provided well below.

what is the best way to filter df, so that only users with no missing values appear.

I have:

```
s[s == 0].index
```

which provides the indices (below is it; above dataframe was just general df)

```
Index([25c90900-cd25-4f51-8634-3eba9821e167,
   29b63a9d-3a60-4d69-b507-145977b0dc49,
   843a997d-5446-41d1-8697-4ded33bba85d,
   690d0511-232c-4bd9-98ae-c9bb101bc18b,
   35a2dabb-ac20-48cb-8d1e-adf53c68d546,
   859591fd-67fc-41b3-823b-33053dbccc47,
   7b8a4cfb-3010-4bc3-9963-14f2b4f6ffdb,
   266f5f1f-0a58-49ca-9e66-7e8d2058a836,
   77b99c57-f37b-48d5-b8b9-68929f31d3fc,
   47afb3d3-98bb-4486-8935-a0b57a2de0c6,
   ...
   e14e69f6-3e33-4d1f-beff-76a35c2e11e9,
   e81c9737-e632-460a-9a12-c6bc7b48341b,
   c63ddb6e-2d89-4188-97c0-794aab70a816,
   4c4a259c-7121-41c7-8e15-f8b87071489a,
   a612b6ee-4143-44a6-9214-81e607d4c9c3,
   9d95839e-94c6-4659-ab88-95159e3a1238,
   04826220-c5eb-4042-a355-217526aed323,
   6054dd2d-9298-49b9-8617-3e156459ab2d,
   3d8aeb80-7473-4d4c-90e6-8603133a7c65,
   0aa7ac36-0274-48ba-86e6-f807645e0559],
  dtype='object', name='uuid', length=2217)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
s = df.isnull().all(axis=1).sum(level=0)
print (s)
user
user1    1.0
user2    1.0
user3    2.0
dtype: float64
```

If need `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df.isnull().all(axis=1).sum(level=0).astype(int).reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
    user  count
0  user1      1
1  user2      1
2  user3      2
```

**Explanation**:

First check `NaN`s values in all columns:

```
print (df.isnull())
             val1   val2   val3
user  cat                      
user1 cat1  False   True   True
      cat2   True   True   True
      cat3   True   True  False
user2 cat1   True   True   True
      cat2   True  False   True
      cat3   True   True  False
user3 cat1  False   True   True
      cat2   True   True   True
      cat3   True   True   True
```

Then check all rows for all `True`s by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
print (df.isnull().all(axis=1))
user   cat 
user1  cat1    False
       cat2     True
       cat3    False
user2  cat1     True
       cat2    False
       cat3    False
user3  cat1    False
       cat2     True
       cat3     True
dtype: bool
```

And then `sum` boolean `True`s like `1`s by `sum`:

```
print (df.isnull().all(axis=1).sum(level=0))
user
user1    1.0
user2    1.0
user3    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks you!! this is exactly what i needed, the explanation really helped as well.

Comment: @hedebyhedge - Thank you for nice question. Small friend advice - you can improve your question if add what you try, your code or some error if rased :)

Comment: quick question. I have s[s == 0].index, which is a list of all user indices that have no missing values. How would I filter df now to only provide those users?

Comment: Use `df = df.loc[idx]`, `idx=s[s == 0].index`